# inside security door

Tags: doors, hardware

EDIT:   Sorry, I didn't realize I couldn't ask this question.  It is in a commercial type setting (it is a non-profit and seperates a living area from another area).

I need to know what kind of door handle to look for.  We have a door access program that uses keyfobs to open the doors.  We also need to be able to use a key from both sides of the door (double keyed) in case the power goes out.  I need the door to open only, not unlock. Any idea what kind of hardware I need to look for?

Comment: Could you provide a picture of the door you're asking about?  Commonly we call a door with a handle that doesn't operate the latch a *passage* door, but a picture would help immensely.

Comment: Is this in a home or somewhere else? Requiring a key (electronic or otherwise) to exit is unusual, and dangerous.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. Take the [tour] for tips. I'd make an effort to do it myself but I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: If the door needs to remain locked from the inside, you need to seriously consider a "crash bar" type for the inside to allow occupants to exit in a panic (like when there's a fire) so they don't have to fumble with a key.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this sounds like a commercial installation (without any evidence from the OP that it isn't), and commercial work is off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

You already know you can't just push a locked door open, because a thing in the door (the **latch**) is blocking a thing in the wall (the **strike**).  And of course you know *normally*, you open the door by having the **latch** retract.  Well, there's a way to have the **strike** retract instead!   So now, *either way* can open the door.

That is called an **electric strike**.

You have your badge system operate the *strike* electrically... and your key system operate the *latch* mechanically.

This is a very common way badge entry systems are set up.  If the electric strike is stone dead, the latch can still be retracted the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Snark free interpretation: Any old keyed door knob/latch will do the trick, since all the key is doing is retracting the latch and it has nothing to do with the electronic operation. (snark not totally inappropriate in this situation). +1